# using mysql min() find next lowest value

Tags: mysql, zero, min

I have a script to find the lowest value from a column but some entries dont have a value or its set to 0 if this is the case I'd like ti to find the next lowest value.

Here is my sql command.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT product_name, format, image_url, MIN(online_price), EAN FROM products where $searchstring and format = '{$cat}' AND EAN != ' ' AND EAN != '-' AND EAN != 'PRERELEASE' AND online_price > '0' group by EAN LIMIT " . ($page-1)*$Limit . ",$Limit");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `AS` clause:

```
MIN(online_price) AS minprice
```

You now have the result in `minprice`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
MIN(IF(online_price=0,NULL,online_price))
```